# How to store songs or lyrics text in database(implement newline)

Tags: database

I want to create a database for lyrics. I am collecting lyrics from some websites. My problem is I am copying the lyrics and those doesn't have any newline character. So, when I will show those lyrics, will it carry the newline automatically or I need to put newline manually ?

I am just confuse about that! If I need to put newline character, than it will be a very big task for me!! Any idea from experts ?

thanks.

Comment: What does your code look like?

Comment: It's really unclear what you're asking. What soft of database? What tools are you using? What exactly are you doing now? Can you show us some sample data? Have you got some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Speaking generally and not knowing your full intentions or design, I recommend displaying the lyrics just as they were displayed where you found them; as a web page.  If you do, you will never have to worry about line breaks within the text of the lyrics when they are stored in the database.

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer. I am still on rnd about my db. May be I will use sqlite database. But you are correct. thanks